# Is it possible to add layers (more rows) of text using one flex item?

Tags: html, css, iframe, gridview, flexbox

I've created a flexbox container element to which my iframe is on the right.

However, I'd like to have two maybe even three layers of text using different tags to the left of it evenly spaced in the width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; div I have. likely an H3 header and a P.

at the moment they're side by side. Flexbox has obviously created another item for the P.

Is there a way to bring the P down below the H3 and make it behave so that it's centered in that item? Also I need the P not to spill out of the item and into the iframe (max-width?)

HTML:

```
    <main>
      <div class="vid-1">
        <h3 id="hide" class="chan-h3-shift">A comprehensive view on the Oculus Go</h3>
        <p id="hide" class="chan-p-shift">This review</p>
        <iframe class="lefttoright" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/momqQl-9-tg" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </main>
```

CSS:

```
    #hide  {
      display: block;
    }

    .vid-1  {
      display: flex;
      width: 1000px;
      padding-bottom: 300px;
      margin: auto;
    }

    iframe  {
      width: 50%;
      height: 300px;
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      transform: translate(500px, 0)
    }

    .chan-h3-shift  {
      font-size: 0.9em;
      padding: 0 0 0 60px;
    }


    .chan-p-shift  {
      padding: 0 800px 0 60px;
    }

    @keyframes lefttoright {
      0%  {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100%  {
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
    }

    .lefttoright  {
      animation-name: lefttoright;
      animation-duration: 3s;
    }
```

Comment: I think you're trying to do Grid's job with Flexbox. Do you want the p tag to be centered both vertically and horizontally? Where exactly do you want the 1000px gap and what do you want to happen in smaller screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want your p and your h3 one on top of the other, the best thing is to use another div to wrap them:

```
 <div class="vid-1">
  <div class="column"> 
    <h3 id="hide" class="chan-h3-shift">A comprehensive view on the Oculus Go</h3>
    <p id="hide" class="chan-p-shift">This review</p>
  </div>
  <iframe class="lefttoright" src="..."></iframe>
 </div>
```

With this css:

```
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Does this do the trick ?